# Can't enable GNOME Shell user theme extension

Tags: gnome, 11.10, themes, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Just installed 11.10 and GNOME Tweak Tool but can't install `gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme` due to it not existing (or so `apt-get install` tells me). Because of that, there is no enabling `user-theme-extensions` in the advanced settings for the GNOME Tweak Tool. I can't find the repository for it anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Geeky Way**

You can install user-themes and other extensions from PPA, since extensions are not available in official repositories. Enter following commands to have themes working.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme`

Now restart gnome-shell using Alt+F2 run dialog and entering `r`.

Enable extension form gnome-tweak-tool and you're done.

**Preferred Alternate Way**

This is by far the easiest way to install "user-themes" extension, as well as many other GNOME shell extensions.

- Just open Firefox (you **CAN NOT** use any other browser, as of now).
- And visit [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/)
- You can search for extension you're looking for, as well explore other great extensions.
- Found the extension? Just click on the **switch** to install it.
- Aah..... by the way for user-themes, you can get it [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/).

**Note:** GNOME Shell doesn't have Alt+F2 Run dialog enabled by default, so if that's the case, you can enable it via Keyboard Settings>Shortcuts>System.

Comment: Ahh there's the elusive repository. Thank you so much. I don't know why I couldn't find it.

Comment: Ya, credit goes to Andrew (author of www.webupd8.org), which is 2nd best place to keep track of Ubuntu-esque stuff after www.omgubuntu.co.uk.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions on: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/themeselector-gnome-shell-extension-to.html ?

I want to add to the answer of above that extensions will, most likely, never be available by ppa (only by thirdparties proberbly, like the website webupd8 does now) extensions will come eventually available by: https://extensions.gnome.org/

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpful.  If the extensions are there, (check extensions folder) but not showing in gnome-tweak-tool, it may be due to errors in the gnome-tweak tool itself

Changed the files

`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/gshellwrapper.py`

and

`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/gsettings.py`

as mentioned in the article below.

Now you should have full access to all shell extensions and there is no longer an error from gnome-tweak-tool

[Click here for details of the fix](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1874010)